# Position absolute in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

I want to place my Views dynamically on my App, so I used Absolute Layout from Xamarin.Forms.
The problem is that when I set a Y position too big it doesn't behave like I want. I want to scrool when the element is off screen but it doesn't work. Do I have to add something or it's impossible with Absolute Layout ?

Comment: You could try put the AbsoluteLayout inside a StackLayout, and then anything extending should allow you to scroll to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an *AbsoluteLayout*, you need to use *RelativeLayout*, because:

**AbsoluteLayout:**

> Elements cannot be positioned off screen using proportional values.

**RelativeLayout:**

> RelativeLayout does support positioning elements outside of its own
>   bounds.

Comment: thank you but even with relative layout it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please share your XAML?

Comment: ok it work now : I add this => `this.Content = new ScrollView { Content = rl };` before I just put `this.Content=rl` rl is my relative layout. And it work with Absolute layou so... Do you have an explanation or ... ?

Comment: That's because when it comes to scrolling, using a ScrollView component is pre-supposed and a must!